# Why is probability sometimes calculated using ordered pairs of outcomes rather than unordered pairs?

Tags: probability

For example, if we are tossing two coins, where each coin falls on either heads ($H$) or tails ($T$), we have the following possible outcomes: $\{H, H \}$, $\{H, T \}$, $\{T, T \}$.

However, when solving some exercises, I noticed that this is not the way to go when looking for the number of possible outcomes in probability. Rather, we conceive of the outcomes of coin tosses as ordered pairs. In this case, we have $(H,H)$, $(H,T)$, $(T,H)$, $(T,T)$.

I don't understand why the first approach is wrong and the rationale of why we need two ordered pairs $(H,T)$  and $(T,H)$ rather than just $\{H,T\}$. Therefore, I don't really understand what probability is about either. Please, help me understand.

Comment: If you use unordered pairs you can't distinguish the two tosses. For $\{H,T\}$, you know you have one head and one tail, but you don't know which is which.

Comment: But why is it crucial that you know which is which? I know that we can know which coin landed on which side only by using ordered pairs, but I don't understand why this would be crucial when calculating probability.

Comment: If you want to calculate the probability that there is first one head and then one tail, then you're computing the probability that a particular ordered pair occurs. Ordered pairs are also the most general; if you want to compute the probability of the unordered pair, it's the sum of the probabilities of the two ordered pairs.

Comment: Good, the problem is that most exercises don't make it clear if probability in the sense of ordered or unordered pairs is wanted. I'll assume that the default is always ordered pairs from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to look at the probability spaces that each generates:

When working with unordered pairs:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Outcome} & \text{Probability} \\ \hline \{H,H\} & 0.25 \\ \{H,T\} & 0.5 \\ \{T,T\} & 0.25\end{array}$$

Note how different outcomes have different probabilities. On the other hand, working with ordered pairs:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Outcome} & \text{Probability} \\ \hline (H,H) & 0.25 \\ (H,T) & 0.25 \\ (T,H) & 0.25 \\ (T,T) & 0.25\end{array}$$

Sample spaces where every outcome is equally probable is called an Equiprobable space. In general, given the choice between two probability spaces, Equiprobable spaces are often (but not always) easier to work with, even though they have some redundant information. But, both probability spaces are valid ways to record the results flipping two fair coins, and in some contexts, you may prefer the probability space of unordered pairs rather than the Equiprobable space.

An example of when you must use a non-equiprobable space is when you are conducting Bernoulli trials. You have a single sample space with two outcomes that are not equiprobable. Now, using unordered pairs tends to be as common (or possibly even more common) than ordered pairs. If the probability of flipping heads on an unfair coin is $0<p<1$, then over the course of ten flips, you wind up with the probability space:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Outcome} & \text{Probability} \\ \hline \text{10 heads} & \dbinom{10}{0}p^{10}(1-p)^0 \\ \text{9 heads, 1 tail} & \dbinom{10}{1}p^9(1-p)^1 \\ \text{8 heads, 2 tails} & \dbinom{10}{2}p^8(1-p)^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ k\text{ heads, }10-k\text{ tails} & \dbinom{10}{k}p^k(1-p)^{10-k}\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for a very insightful answer! :) Although it bugs me that the exercises I get do not specify which probability space I have to work in and thus suffer from vagueness.